# Replace number in a string using regex or something else

Tags: javascript, regex

I am not so good with regex. I am struggling to find a solution for a small functionality.

I have a ajax response which returns a string like **"Your ticket has been successfully logged. Please follow the link to view details 123432."**

All I have to do is replace that number **123432** with `<a href="blablabla.com?ticket=123432">` using javascript.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this:

```
fixedString = yourString.replace(/(\d+)/g, 
    "<a href='blablabla.com?ticket=$1\'>$1</a>");
```

This will give you a new string that looks like this:

> `Your ticket has been successfully logged. Please follow the link to view details <a href='blablabla.com?ticket=123432'>123432</a>.`

Comment: Notice that the replacement text is not constant.

Comment: Shouldn't that be fixedString = yourString.replace(/(\d+)/g, 
    "<a href='blablabla.com?ticket=$1\'>$1</a>");

Comment: @Chad - Yes it should - nice call :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = "Your ticket has been successfully logged. Please follow the link to view details 123432.";
str = str.replace(/\s+(\d+)\.$/g, '<a href="blablabla.com?ticket=$1">$&</a>');
```

this code will output

```
<a href="blablabla.com?ticket=123432">Your ticket has been successfully logged. Please follow the link to view details 123432.</a>
```