# javascript to replace all instances of a text within [] with hyperlinks

Tags: javascript, regex

Am now facing an other challenge. Some parts of my html code has the following lines:

```
<div class="action-body flooded"><p>(In <span class="error">&#91;82681&#93;</span>)         refs <a href="/browse/AGLBD-16096" title="GlobalTestSuite tracking">AGLBD-16096</a><br/></div>
```

I have to get the number with-in the [] and then replace it with a hyperlink. I have tried using document.getElementsByClassName('error') but its not working. how can I make it work? and i would also need to iterate in a loop to replace all such numbers if there are more than one in []. e.g: [123] [234] [345]...

This is all what I have written till now with pimvdb's help:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var bodyText = document.getElementById('body').innerHTML;
var pattern = /\[.*?\]/g;
var replaceText = "<a href=\"www.mysite.com\">Pradeep</a>";
document.getElementById('body').innerHTML = bodyText.replace(pattern, replaceText);
</script>
```

Comment: `document.body` gives you the body element.  What you're using looks for an element with the id _body_.  Otherwise, this appears to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This JSFiddle does what you need: http://jsfiddle.net/TNyms/

Answer (score 1):

When you replace `getElementById('body')` with `document.body`, the code works for me.

```
var body = document.body;
var link = "<a href=\"http://www.mysite.com\">Pradeep</a>";
body.innerHTML = body.innerHTML.replace(/\[.*?\]/g, link);
```

That replaces all IDs in this with links:

```
<div class="action-body flooded">
    <p>(In
        <span class="error">&#91;82681&#93;</span>) refs
        <a href="/browse/AGLBD-16096" title="">AGLBD-16096</a>
        <br/>
</div>
<div>[123][abcd]</div>
<div>[456]</div>
<div>[789]</div>
```

Outputs:

> (In [Pradeep](http://www.mysite.com)) refs AGLBD-16096
>
> [Pradeep](http://www.mysite.com)[Pradeep](http://www.mysite.com)
>
> [Pradeep](http://www.mysite.com)
>
> [Pradeep](http://www.mysite.com)

Try it with [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xYBJc/).

Answer (score 0):

Your question appears to be related to what is asked in the below link. You may refer this

[Replace number in a string using regex or something else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2677730/replace-number-in-a-string-using-regex-or-something-else)